# inserting values from one table to another by checking certain fields

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following table named `screening_plan`:

```
plan_id movie_id  plan_start_day  plan_end_day plan_min_start_hh24  plan_max_start_hh24 screenings
    1    1        1/06/2015       28/06/2015       9                  17                  5 
    2    2        1/06/2015       28/06/2015       9                  22                  4 
    3    3        1/06/2015       28/06/2015       9                  22                  5 
    4    4        1/06/2015       28/06/2015       9                  17                  4
```

And another tables `theatre`:

```
THEATRE_ID THEATRE_DESCRIPTION THEATRE_TOTAL_ROWS
         1                            2
         2                            2
         3                            3
         4                            2
```

The manager wants the first movie (`movie_id = 1`) to be screened in the biggest theatre and have an additional screening in another theatre at the busiest time of the day (about lunch time). It means that there will be 2 concurrent screenings of the first movie around lunch time. The second movie is in the second biggest theatre.

I have to provide screening information for the first day in the table `screening` as follows(upto screening_id=18):

```
screening_id    plan_id theatre_id  screening_date  screening_start_hh24    screening_start_mm60
     1             1      3          1/06/2015          9                       0
     2             1      3          1/06/2015          11                      30
     3             1      3          1/06/2015          14                      0
     4                               1/06/2015
```

Please note that there is at least a break of 30 minutes between 2 consecutive screenings in the same theatre.
`plan_id` is a foreign key referring table `screening` and `theatre_id` is a foreign key referring table `theatre`.

My code:

```
DECLARE
  s_plan_id NUMBER;
  s_theatre_id NUMBER;
  s_screening_date DATE;
  s_screening_start_hh24 NUMBER;
  s_screening_start_mm60 NUMBER:=0;
  s_count_theatre_id NUMBER;

  BEGIN

  SELECT plan_id INTO s_plan_id FROM  screening_plan  WHERE plan_id=1;
  SELECT theatre_id INTO s_theatre_id FROM theatre WHERE theatre_id=1;
  SELECT PLAN_START_DATE INTO s_screening_date FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id=1;
  SELECT PLAN_MIN_START_HH24 INTO s_screening_start_hh24 FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id=1;
  SELECT Count(*) INTO s_count_theatre_id FROM screening WHERE theatre_id=1;                                                        
  --SELECT PLAN_MAX_START_HH24 INTO s_screening_start_mm60 FROM screening_plan WHERE plan_id=1;

  IF s_count_theatre_id = 0 
  THEN
  INSERT INTO screening (plan_id, theatre_id, screening_date, screening_start_hh24, screening_start_mm60) 
  VALUES
  ( s_plan_id,
  s_theatre_id,
  s_screening_date,
  s_screening_start_hh24,
  s_screening_start_mm60);

  ELSIF s_count_theatre_id <= 4 
  THEN
    IF s_screening_start_hh24=9 AND s_screening_start_mm60=0
    then
         s_screening_start_hh24:=11 ;
         s_screening_start_mm60:=30 ;

  INSERT INTO screening (plan_id, theatre_id, screening_date, screening_start_hh24, screening_start_mm60) 
  VALUES
  ( s_plan_id,
  s_theatre_id,
  s_screening_date,
  s_screening_start_hh24,
  s_screening_start_mm60);
  END if;
  END if;

END;
```

There is no problem with the `plan_id, theatre_id and screening_date`. Now I have to write a logic for `screening_start_hh24` and `screening_start_mm60`. I can use the IF-Else statement, but that would be hard-coding. So, I just wanted to know if anybody could help with looping to create a 30 mins interval between two consecutive screenings.

Comment: what is your question and what have you done so far to solve your problem?

Comment: @davegreen100 you should ask her/his teacher

Comment: @Typo please see the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a Stored Procedure with your code, lets call it SCHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE

Then you could create a Scheduled job to run the procedure every 30 minutes like this:

```
sys.dbms_scheduler.create_job(job_name => 'A name for the job', 
                                        job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
                                        job_action => 'SCHEMA.MY_PROCEDURE',
                                        start_date => to_date('24-06-2015 00:05:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),
                                        repeat_interval => 'Freq=hourly; interval=30',
                                        end_date => to_date(null),
                                        job_class => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS',
                                        enabled => true,
                                        auto_drop => true,
                                        comments => 'Some comment');
```

[Here's some info about the scheduler package](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g#programs)

Comment: That's not what I am looking for. All I have to do is store the movies in the screening table on the basis of no. of screenings for that movie. And the start_screening_hh24 should be less or equal to the plan_max_start_hh24 from the screening_plan table.